# Locally connected 2D layer without summation over colors - keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, convolution, keras-layer

I want to create a neural network with a locally connected layer but without summation over the 3rd dimension (colors) of the inputs.

I saw in the docs of [LocallyConnected2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LocallyConnected2D) that there is no "group" argument as in the conv2d.

Is there a way to do that?